# How to ETL postgresql columns which contain HTML code via csv copy

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, etl

I need to ETL data between two postgresql data bases. Several of the columns needing to be transferred contain HTML code. The is several million rows and i need to move this via csv copy for speed reasons. While trying to csv.writer and copy_from the csv file the characters in the HTML code are causing errors with the transfer making it seemingly impossible to set a delimiter or handle quoting

I am running this ETL job via python and have used .replace() on the columns to make ';' work as a delimiter.

However, I am running into issues with page breaks and paragraphs in the HTML code (
 and

specifically) and quoting fields. When i encounter these i receive the error that there is 'missing data for column'

I have tried setting 'doublequote' and changing the escape character to '\'. I have also tried changing the quotechar to '|'

The code I am using to create the csv is:

```py
filename = 'transfer.csv'
with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|',
                           quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

The code i am using to load the csv is:

```py
f = open(file_path, "r")
print('File opened')
cur.copy_from(f, stage_table, sep=';', null="")
```

As mentioned above, the error message that i receive when i try to import the csv is: "Error: missing data for column"

I would love to be able to format my csv.writer and copy_from code in such a way that i do not have to use dozens or more nested replace() statements and transforms to ETL this data and can have an automated script run it on a schedule.

Comment: Do you have the option of using postgres_fdw to copy the data directly from the other db?  If not, can you export the csv directly from the primary db using psql and \copy?  I don't see a reason to involve python in this.

Comment: Yes, if you can use PostgreSQL's `COPY`, the resulting file would be correct.

Comment: Firstly, Thank you for the input. I am involving python as this is being scheduled and run via an Airflow DAG. Additionally, I am pulling the data from a redshift database which i am still fairly new in working with. I will try and reconfigure for using the postgres copy command. instead of the copy_from.